# Xcode 6 configuration during distribution to App store

Tags: xcode6, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to set all configurations before I distribute my app to the app store. I set code signing debug to developer and release to distribution. Also, I set the provisioning to debug to development and release the distribution. Besides, I have faced a problem after my first distribution to app store. The problem was that notifications could not be sent to users. However, notification could be sent to users with development APNS certificate. I thought that I have a missing configuration on Xcode.

What can be the reason of this ?

Thank you for your answers,

Best regards

**EDIT:** Problem solved by deleting APNS distribution certificate from my server build path and recreated a new p12 file from keychain and added it to server build path again. It works without any problem.

Comment: If you are building your app with Appstore provison profile then notification should be sent via Production APNS certificate.

Comment: No, I am not building with Appstore provisioning profile, I extra added ad-hoc cert in order to test production notification. Also, I use Moon-Apns for push notification in c# and its "use sandbox" parameter is false in distribution environment. Do you have an idea about this ?

Comment: No but it should not be sandbox if you are using ad-hoc or appstore certificates.

Comment: Ok, I already dont use sandbox when I try to test in distribution environment. When you set "use sandbox" parameter as false, MoonApns send your notification through apple's production server. However, even I set that parameter as false, it doesn't work. I didn't understand that why.